# Bar Chart (Google Charts) with Vertical or Point Marker

Tags: javascript, visualization, google-visualization, data-visualization

I am starting to work in visualizations and I am using Google Chart, I am trying to do a Bar Chart

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

In which I could set a marker in a horizontal bar as a vertical line preferably or maybe a circle point to point out any value of my interest. Another option that could provide a way of marking a specific point in the bar chart would probably alright aswell.

So any of you does know a way of doing this kind of Bar Chart with a Marker?

Edited: The graph should look similar to this one:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=100x40&cht=bhs&chco=000000&chd=t:65&chbh=15&chm=r,ff0000,0,0.49,0.51,1

However not as an image but being able to interact with the object as it can be done using Bar Chart visualization.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not like this answer because it does not propose a solution using google-charts, but if you bear with me a second, you might find this useful, or at least informative. Anyway, pure HTML and CSS graphing solutions are not going to provide the opportunity for many advanced visualizations, but I am of the opinion - based on real world experience - that you can do quite a lot with just CSS and HTML in regards to bar charts. I recommend reading Wilson Miner's article on A List Apart called [Accessible Data Visualization with Web Standards](http://alistapart.com/article/accessibledatavisualization)

Then consider the following quick and dirty CSS/HTML graphs in this fiddle that mimic the chart you are looking to implement.

http://jsfiddle.net/9mJzd/

I will paste merely a snippet of the Bars here. You will also need to review the CSS in the fiddle.

```
<td>
    <div class="BarWrap">
       <div class="BarBar" style="width: 100%;" title="Ty Cabbage: .426"></div>
       <div class="BarAvg" style="left: 62%" title="League Average: .278"></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Just add jQuery and a tooltip plugin (such as jQuery UI's tooltip), and you have *started* to add some interactivity to your bar chart.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is not what I was looking for, but it sure will cover what I explained